# Implementing full screen video in website via button

Tags: html

I need to add videos to my website that function in this sort of fashion:
http://www.google.com/nexus/5/ .

I like:

- how the `Watch again` button causes the Youtube video to take up the whole section of that page
- how you are able to close it whenever you want with the "X" button

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was done with YouTube's JS API to me: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
So essentially, get the `<iframe>` embed code from YouTube, then append &enablejsapi=1 to the end of the src attribute. Then, call the mute() function on the iframe to mute it. Your "Watch Now" button could unmute the video using the unMute() function and go back to the beginning with seekTo(0, true).

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls